# Tensorflow: Change input and output of tensorflowhub model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-hub

I would like to change the input and output size of a convolutional model of tensorflow, which I am importing from the tensorflow hub.

Would I like to know what is the best way to do this? If I could convert the model to kaeras format I think it would be easier, but I'm not succeeding either.

This is the model https://tfhub.dev/intel/midas/v2_1_small/1

Comment: I don't think that is possible, or would be very hacky. Could broke the model I think.

Comment: There is another input size option in https://tfhub.dev/intel/midas/v2/2.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the input is determined by the publisher of the model. Some models could be flexible on the dimensions of the input and some require input with very specific dimensions. In that case, the best way would be to resize the input as needed before feeding it to the model.

Comment: yes, adjusting the input is always necessary before using the model. But in my particular case I want to change the input size of the model because I am running on mobile and the inference time is too much.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case there is not much one can do besides contacting the publisher to see if they could publish a version that is more mobile-friendly version of a model. One long shot could be to try to generate a full end-to-end model in TF SavedModel format than convert it to TFLite using the [TFLite converter tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter?hl=en). Tweaking converter options may result in faster model.